# Random crash on MapKit when when try to remove all MKAnnotations based on iOS 6.1.

Tags: ios, crash, mapkit, mkannotationview

Using MapKit based on iOS6.1, app will random crash (very low occurrence rate) when I try to remove all MKAnnotations then pop out map view controller. From the crash log it seems be an observer issue, anyone who has experienced the similar issue please give me some insight, any idea or discussion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS:

UIMapView is a singleton in my app, only create once.

```
2013-08-13 15:11:59.025 CHSP[9129:c07] CRASH: Cannot remove an observer <MKAnnotationContainerView 0xb8e5120> for the key path "title" from <MKUserLocation 0xbab3440> because it is not registered as an observer.

2013-08-13 15:11:59.060 CHSP[9129:c07] Stack Trace: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x028ff02e __exceptionPreprocess + 206
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02030e7e objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x028fedeb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
3   Foundation                          0x01a84a89 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverRegistration) _removeObserver:forProperty:] + 790
4   Foundation                          0x01a8471d -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverRegistration) removeObserver:forKeyPath:] + 105
5   MapKit                              0x009194f9 -[MKAnnotationContainerView _unregisterObserverForBubbleAnnotation:] + 116
6   MapKit                              0x00919704 -[MKAnnotationContainerView setBubbleAnnotationView:] + 99
7   MapKit                              0x0091925d -[MKAnnotationContainerView _removeBubbleWithAnimation:tellDelegate:] + 247
8   MapKit                              0x0091b114 -[MKAnnotationContainerView _deselectAnnotationViewWithAnimation:tellDelegate:] + 128
9   MapKit                              0x0091b1e1 -[MKAnnotationContainerView _deselectAnnotationView] + 49
10  MapKit                              0x0092198e -[MKAnnotationContainerView _removeAnnotationView:updateCollections:] + 395
11  MapKit                              0x009217fe -[MKAnnotationContainerView _removeAnnotationView:] + 48
12  MapKit                              0x00921490 -[MKAnnotationContainerView removeAnnotation:] + 375
13  MapKit                              0x00921538 -[MKAnnotationContainerView removeAnnotations:] + 160
14  MapKit                              0x0090f8bd -[MKMapView removeAnnotations:] + 58
15  CHSP                                0x00077fd5 -[UPNewMapViewController removeAllAnnotations] + 101
16  CHSP                                0x00076640 -[UPNewMapViewController dealloc] + 64
17  UIKit                               0x01055480 -[UIViewController release] + 93
18  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x020430c3 objc_release + 51
19  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02043bd9 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv + 555
20  CoreFoundation                      0x028a1468 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 24
21  CoreFoundation                      0x028a5afd __CFRunLoopRun + 1933
22  CoreFoundation                      0x028a4f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
23  CoreFoundation                      0x028a4e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
24  GraphicsServices                    0x02c927e3 GSEventRunModal + 88
25  GraphicsServices                    0x02c92668 GSEventRun + 104
26  UIKit                               0x00f7753c UIApplicationMain + 1211
27  CHSP                                0x0009d9a2 main + 130
28  CHSP                                0x00002f55 start + 53
)

2013-08-13 15:11:59.061 CHSP[9129:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Cannot remove an observer <MKAnnotationContainerView 0xb8e5120> for the key path "title" from <MKUserLocation 0xbab3440> because it is not registered as an observer.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by myself. 
Originally I try to use another image to show user current location instead of Mapkit default one, seems it is not a good idea.

Comment: Hacking or customize MapKit default control lookout may in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the actual problem.
I can consistently reproduce the issue (even on iOS 5.1) with the following sequence:

1) have your app show annotations + user location

2) press home button to push app to background

3) disable location services and wait until the app is really stopped (I waited 60seconds)

4) go back to app (in my case my app was setup to update as soon as it is started, which will cause it to try to remove old annotations before adding new ones)

=> here the app will crash.

I debugged it by doing my own "removeAnnotations:" method by iterating thru all of them and I found that when it crashed it was trying to remove one more annotation than I had initially added.

The problem did not happen if user location was not shown (either because location services was never enabled, either because other reasons), so I figured it would be a sort of race, because when disabling location services in step 3) above, MKMapView will remove automatically the user location once it found out location services are disabled. However, if the app grabbed the annotations array before, it would still contain the userlocation, which is being released/destroyed in a separate thread by MKMapView, hence the race.

So the answer is that you need to remove only the annotations you added. Here's my code:

```
- (void)removeAnnotations
{
    NSArray *currentAnnotations = [m_MapView annotations];
    int count = [[m_MapView annotations] count];

    if (currentAnnotations && count)
    {
        NSMutableArray *annotationsToRemove = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];

        for (id annotation in currentAnnotations)
        {
            if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]])
            {
                [annotationsToRemove addObject:annotation];
            }
        }

        DBGLOG(@"removeAnnotations: current_count %d, to_be_removed_count %d\n", count, [annotationsToRemove count]);

        [m_MapView removeAnnotations:annotationsToRemove];
        annotationsToRemove = nil;
    }
    currentAnnotations = nil;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you guy. My case was finally fixed by the root cause I overwrote user location annotation view, and try to manipulate it from time to time.

Comment: You are right, you'd better not to add/remove user current location annotation.